# How to use a field value for IN() condition?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have following structures:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `proxies` (
  `proxy_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `proxy_ip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proxy_port` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `proxy_country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`proxy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_range` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I have 3 rows in `proxies` table with country names of Germany, Finland and France. The `ip_range` Field in `accounts` tables holds list of `proxy_id`s separated by `,` character.

Now I have a query like this:

```sql
SELECT accounts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(proxy_country) countries
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN `proxies` ON `proxy_id` IN (`ip_range`)
GROUP BY `account_id`
```

I expected something like this:

| account_id | username | password | ip_range | countries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | pass | 1,2,3 | Germany,France,Finland |

But what i get is:

| account_id | username | password | ip_range | countries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | pass | 1,2,3 | Germany |

As i noticed, `ip_range` Will cast as text so my query is something like

```sql
SELECT accounts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(proxy_country) countries
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN `proxies` ON `proxy_id` IN ('1,2,3')
GROUP BY `account_id`
```

That is wrong. it should be:

```sql
SELECT accounts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(proxy_country) countries
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN `proxies` ON `proxy_id` IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY `account_id`
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input data that give you that output?

Comment: @ErgestBasha There is nothing here to suggest that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, although OP has admitted that it is. All the columns in `accounts` are functionally dependant on `account_id` (PK) and `proxy_country` is in an aggregate function.

Comment: @user1191247 you are right I missed the `account_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` , still  `select table.*`  will make other queries fail with sql_mode only_full_group_by enabled.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Agreed! `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` should always be enabled.

Comment: What programming language are you using to build `IN ('1,2,3')`?  Or is "1,2,3" sitting in some table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `IN`  you need single values, for searching strings You use `FIND_IN SET` like below

```
SELECT accounts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(proxy_country) countries
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN `proxies` ON FIND_IN_SET(`proxy_id` , `ip_range`)
GROUP BY `account_id`
```

But you should read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and normalize your table structure, every string function  is slow.

As erwin noted that your code, is not very good, as FULL_GROUP BY would cause an error and since MySQL 8 is activated by default.
[Read more about GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

So a better solution would be

```
SELECT accounts.account_id,accounts.username,accounts.password
       ,accounts.ip_range, GROUP_CONCAT(proxy_country) countries
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN `proxies` ON FIND_IN_SET(`proxy_id` , `ip_range`)
GROUP BY accounts.account_id,accounts.username
         ,accounts.password, accounts.ip_range
```

`SELECT *` is a bad habit, and should also be avoided.

Comment: Oh. totally forgot about `FIND_IN_SET`. Thanks for the note. And about the structure, i`m not in position to decide to change it, but in personal experience, sometimes we could say fk the normalize and then our queries will get so lightweight... And yes. i agree that string functions are slow, sadly.

Comment: @ErgestBasha IDK why you ask to enable only_full_group_by to get query fail running. my current sql_mode is empty, not for this query but for the whole engine. please explain in details.

Comment: you can use it in 5.7 and 5.6 balso, but it can be disabled also in mysql 8 also, but it is a good point. @BehzadSafamanesh as tables and REsult sets are unsorted by nature, the result of your query could not be deterministic,  full GROUP By will remove that

Comment: @BehzadSafamanesh because I seen a lot of questions in this forum related to the only_full_group_by . As nbk already mentioned you can't control which data will be returned if a column in the select statement is not part of an aggregate function such as min(),max() etc..  nor part of the group by clause . Your query might give inconsistent data .